# Reading an attachment that gmail doesn't render

Tags: email, images, gmail, attachments

I was recently sent an email attachment that Gmail doesn't render. It's very important that I get access to this attachment, but I can't for the life of me figure out how. I know that the attachment was sent because I looked at the plain text, and saw this:

```
--001636e0b0a2d5b97304a97d51d0
Content-Type: image/gif; name="image001.gif"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <image001.gif@01CC487A.BD9DFF00>
X-Attachment-Id: 8178a39d9dae1f7_0.1

R0lGODlhyADIAJH/AP//////zMzM/8zMzCwAAAAAyADIAEAC/4SPqcvtD6OctNqLnQDb9vMhAxAI

(Continues like above for some time)

UJcLcq+Jc5WnVxorp4tjJue42NYKmQ00ZcmuiGKcK1ZC7lQFiQAAOw==
--001636e0b0a2d5b97304a97d51d0--
```

Note, to cut down on the size of this, and to ensure some privacy for what was emailed, I've omitted what is around maybe 500 lines of similar looking text.

So, my question is, how can I recover this image? I'm sure there has to be a way, that I'm not the only user to ever face this problem, but I'm having problems figuring it out.

Comment: That just looks like header info. Isn't there somewhere else where it say "Download"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps feed the text after `X-Attachment-Id: 8178a39d9dae1f7_0.1` to a [base64 decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) & save the recoded.. content as an image file?

Comment: Hmmm... That worked, but gave me an image that  doesn't seem to contain anything interesting at all... Sigh. Guess they must have messed up the original. Thanks!

Comment: welcome @Pearsonartphoto